# Extract files out of Solaris pkg file without installing

Tags: solaris

How can I extract the binaries out of a pkg file without adding them to the default locations under `/usr` or other default folder. I want to add this package under my own directory `/our_own_directory/our_own_prefix_specific_for_this_package` so it is self contained, easy to know what is going on, and is tied to our application directories instead of OS directories.

Also, I don't want to touch the global database of installed packages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Though this won't install the package, you can transfer them from a package file (aka a datastream package) to a spool location with the pkgtrans command:

> pkgtrans filename.pkg /home/user/existing_temporary_package_prefix_dir

This will extract the package file system hierarchy as well as the pkginfo file and any pre/post install scripts into your directory.

Comment: Would it be necessary to execute any post install script using this strategy that bypasses standard package installation?